# Stick 20% image at the Top while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal Window, consisting of:

1. an Image and a list down with comments on that image.(scrollable with `overflow:auto`)
2. The Modal window also has a Add comment Textarea at the bottom.

I want to acheive the following functionality:
When the comment section is scrolled up, I wanted to stick the bottom 20% of the image on the top and then scroll the comments below

Please refer the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9u9mztqs/1/

Images for reference

[image: Image 1 For reference]

[image: Image 2 For reference]

---

Comment: i don't understand your question 100% - you want the bottom 20% of the  image to be displayed when scrolling up?

Comment: yes! the image would scroll up, but will stick once reaches 80%(can be any value ofcourse), and the rest of the comments which are displayed at the bottom should scroll up. But the 20% bottom of the image would stick at top of the Modal Window

Comment: why don't you just make your comments div scrollable? like here: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/B4ppp/

Comment: @messerbill I need to show a portion of image on the top :(

Answer (score 0):

so, i created a fiddle doing the job, but it does not look very beautiful yet...this is your job ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/9u9mztqs/2/

i hope this will solve your problem.

```
if (windowpos == 0) {
               s.removeClass('stick_in');
               s.addClass('stick_out');}
        }
```

the image will be resized by scrolling up to the top. Of course you can insert any value you want to here.

Comment: doesnt work: The image doesnt un-stick once it sticks on the top.

Comment: it does at my place - which browser do u use?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple ***basis*** for the feature you want. I suppose the code is self-explanatory, but if you have questions concerning the implementation do ask please.

You are advised to throttle the scroll event handling, otherwise it potential will take a huge performance hit on your application.

Learn more about [throttling an event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/). And consider reading this discussion on [potential problem that may arise if you do not throttle](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/).

Finally, [**here's an update to your original fiddle, containing the solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/9u9mztqs/4/). Below is a summary of the fiddle content.

### Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imageHeight, scrollTopThreshold;
  var heading = $("#heading"),
    body = $("body"),
    img = $("#heading img");

  img.on("load", function() {
    imageHeight = $(this).height();
    // actually sticks (100 - 70)% of picture
    // if you really want 20%, then change 70 with 80.
    scrollTopThreshold = Math.ceil(imageHeight * 70 / 100);
  });

  $(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
    if (body.scrollTop() >= scrollTopThreshold) {
      heading.css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: -scrollTopThreshold + "px"
      });
    } else {
      heading.css({
        position: "inherit",
        top: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

### Style

```
#heading,
#heading img {
  width: 100%;
}
#comment-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  resize: none;
}
```

### Markup

```
<div id="heading">
  <img src="http://www.rtacpa.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/rotator/sample-1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<ol class="main">
  <li>I didn't think it was that bad</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
  <li>So bad that you ate it all</li>
</ol>
<form name="comment-form" id="comment-form" action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" style="" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Say something..." maxlength="250"></textarea>
  <button type="button">Post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer: But the problem arise when it is a BootStrap Modal.. the div works well on a simple html page but not in the Modal Window

Comment: Try execute the code with the above button. It doesnt seems to work

Comment: It might not be clear that it works using the ***Run code snippet*** button. Use the updated fiddle to try it. Finally, this answer solves your question basically, but if you are not willing to add some effort to get it up to your taste, then that's your own failing. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but the issue was specifically for the BootsTrap modal.. if it is not a modal, i have a simpler solution for it.. but the Problem is when it is a Modal.

Comment: unfortunately, the fiddle doesnt work either: Please refer http://postimg.org/image/vef6oa9en/

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the working fiddle: http://s27.postimg.org/yo158swdf/fiddle.png

Comment: All I had to do was navigate to fiddle location and scroll. In your question, you asked for how to set an element to a fixed position after scrolling a certain part of the page away, and that's exactly what this answer provides. The answer provides you a good foundation that can prime a production-ready solution. You need too put in some effort of your own to help yourself.